# Google Maps directions change the names every few days

Tags: javascript, google-maps

My previous code was:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(d, 'directions_changed', function() {
    console.log(d.directions.Wb.origin.b); //lat
  });
```

Now it works only with:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(d, 'directions_changed', function() {
    console.log(d.directions.Vb.origin.d); //lat
  });
```

And these values change every few days. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that those properties are not meant for public consumption as they are not listed in the API documentation.

To get the origin use the API documented methods and properties:

```
var origin = d.directions.routes[0].legs[0].start_location;

var lat = origin.lat();
var lng= origin.lng();
```